# Minimum of two Wiener process

Tags: random, independence

I came to this question that if we have $Z(t)=\min\{ X(t),Y(t) \}$, where $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are two independent Wiener processes, can we say that $Z(t)$ is also a Wiener process?

What if $X(t)=\min\{ X(t-a)+t,Y(t-a)+d\}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, $Z(t)$ is not even a Gaussian process, so the answer is a resounding no.

Comment: Is there a stochastic process that is close to Min, Max operations?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean, for which type of stochastic processes of X(t) and Y(t) we can say for example Z(t)=min{X(t),Y(t)}, is also a stochastic process?

Comment: Well, that one is easy. All of them! You just wrote the definition of a stochastic process Z(t). The problem is with *what kind* of process you get. You can't expect to get a new process of the same kind, or even one on the standard list of “typical” processes. Don't take my word for it, though; we are rapidly moving away from my areas of knowledge. Perhaps you should think more carefully about what you need, then ask a new question. I am likely the only one to see comments on this question/answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed the problem goes as follows: A person (X) is following (stalking) another person (Y) in a long street (one directional movement). X walks as fast as possible while maintaining the minimum distance (d) of Y. If  X(t) is position of the X, and Y(t) is the position of Y at time "t" in the street,  we have X(t)=min{X(t-u)+v*u,Y(t-u)-d}. If Y follows a Wiener diffusion process, what can we say about X? knowing that X in free walking case (the first term) would have the same stochastic process as Y. Hope now it is clear :)

Comment: The verbal description is much clearer than the given formula, which does not fit the description as far as I can tell. And what is $u$ in that formula? It will be impossible for X to follow the recipe, for if, at any time, he is at distance $d$ from Y, the distance will be less than $d$ for some time in an arbitrarily small time interval afterwards, due to the small time behaviour of Wiener diffusion (unlimited speeds, while X can not go faster in any direction (?) than $v$). In any case, a new question would be the way to go here.

Comment: u is a fixed (safety) time distance. Imagine it as the time difference between the time Y starts to move and the time X  starts to follow.  For "the distance will be less than d for some time" as you said, we can put an extra  safety time h. So in that case the total  time distance would be u+d/v+h. The movement is in one direction, assume they are two trains moving on a track.  The distance should be kept until one reached to terminal and stops on a side track. After which the other one can enter the terminal and stop on another side track.

Comment: I need to add the there is no unlimited speed assumption. The max speed is v for both X and Y. And we know that Y(t)=c-vt+s*W(t), such at that Var[Y(t)]=t*s^2. I hope this does not make it more confusing! Thanks

Comment: Well, the Wiener process has unlimited speed, so then Y(t) is not a Wiener process. In any case, this post is now so far removed from the front page nobody is likely to read it anymore. I really think you do need to ask a new question, making it as specific as you can.